Google Maps Geocoding Coordinates Search Problem
I have the dataset.They are like this:

My code is like this:
def get_city(latitude, longitude, api_key):
    """Google Maps Geocoding API to determine the city from coordinates."""
    url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={latitude},{longitude}&key={api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        results = response.json().get('results', [])
        if results:
            for component in results[0]['address_components']:
                if 'locality' in component['types']:
                    return component['long_name']
                elif 'administrative_area_level_1' in component['types']:
                    return component['long_name']
    return "Not Found"

data['City'] = data.apply(lambda row: get_city(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'], api_key), axis=1)


But my output is like this:

I want to search my coordinates via Google Geocoding API and find out which city my coordinates are in.

I do not have a Google API, but I know that your issue comes from the fact that you have the N, W, S, E mention in your columns. You need to remove them. With geopy your code would look like this:
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd

def get_city_geopy(latitude, longitude):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
    location = geolocator.reverse(f"{latitude}, {longitude}", exactly_one=True)
    if location:
        address = location.raw.get('address', {})
        return address.get('city', address.get('town', address.get('village', 'Not Found')))
    return "Not Found"

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Mahalle': ['Ortahisar'],
    'Longitude': ['34.8668937"E'],
    'Latitude': ['38.626686"N']
})

def convert_to_decimal(coord):
    coord = coord.strip('\"NSEW')
    return float(coord)

data['Latitude'] = data['Latitude'].apply(convert_to_decimal)
data['Longitude'] = data['Longitude'].apply(convert_to_decimal)

data['City'] = data.apply(lambda row: get_city_geopy(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']), axis=1)

data

which will give you the name of the city Ortahisar Beldesi. With Google Map API, the function
def get_city_geopy(latitude, longitude):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
    location = geolocator.reverse(f"{latitude}, {longitude}", exactly_one=True)
    if location:
        address = location.raw.get('address', {})
        return address.get('city', address.get('town', address.get('village', 'Not Found')))
    return "Not Found"

must be
def get_city(latitude, longitude, api_key):
    url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={latitude},{longitude}&key={api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        results = response.json().get('results', [])
        if results:
            for component in results[0]['address_components']:
                if 'locality' in component['types']:
                    return component['long_name']
                elif 'administrative_area_level_1' in component['types']:
                    return component['long_name']
    return "Not Found"

that is, exactly the function you gave.
